# Displaying UTF-16 strings in VS debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, unicode

I am developing a C++ program in VS 2012. My program needs to support several different languages so I am using UTF-16. When I hover the mouse over strings while debugging, Visual Studio displays the contents of the string. Unfortunately when that string isn't in English the display is gibberish. Here is an example of what it looks like:

```
L"×××× ×ª×××¨  ××× ×× ××§×  ×¢×× ××× ××¨×× ××¨× ××©×××× ×××ª×¨"
```

Is there any way to make VS display the string correctly while debugging?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, no, that works well.  Rather important on a utf-16 operating system.  It is utterly unguessable what might have gone wrong from your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, you are saying that that this usually works but I must have screwed something up? Maybe it is important to note that I am using a mixture of LTR and RTL languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem was I didn't open the file in binary mode and that was why the string was screwed up. You are supposed to open binary files like this:

```
std::wifstream in(fileName,std::ios::binary);
in.imbue(std::locale(in.getloc(),
  new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));
```